# If statement in filemaker report

Tags: database, filemaker

This report is working fine but is generating report if vendor is unpaid also. i want to have a criteria here. `If[CustomerPaid+VendorPaid==TotalAmount] End If;` Report should generate if this condition pass only. how to go with it? Please help me out

```
    New Window[Name: "Report"; height: 700; width: 900; Left; Style: Document]
Enter Find Mode[]
Go to Layout["Economic Report(Finance)"]
Set Field[Finance::PaidDate; Finance: ReportDateFrom & "..." & Finance::ReportDateTo]
Set Field[Finance::Customer Status;
    "Paid by"]
Set Field[Finance::Vendor Status;
    "Paid by"]
//New Record/Request
//Set Field[Finance::Customer Status;"Unpaid"]
// Omit Record`enter code here`
//New Record/Request
//Set Field[Finance::Customer Status;"Only_Deposit_Received"]
//Omit Record
Perform Find[]
Sort Records[Restore; No dialog]
Pause / Resume Script[Indefinitely]
Print[]
Close Window[Current Window]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot enter a formula as a search criterion. Either define a OutstandingBalance field =

```
TotalAmount - CustomerPaid - VendorPaid
```

and search for 0 in this field, or find records that meet the other criteria (date range, status...) and loop among them, omitting records where:

```
CustomerPaid + VendorPaid ≠ TotalAmount
```

--
Another option is to use ExecuteSQL() to "perform the find" - but then you'd have to format the **text results** for printing, instead of using a report layout.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @michel. can you please help tell me how to use the text results by editing the above code?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I only mentioned this as another option. The formatting can vary wildly, depends on what your query was and how exactly do you want the result to look. If you want to go that way (and this wouldn't be my first choice), try it first - then ask more specific questions as they come.